# replace '.' with ',' from a loaded xml

Tags: php, xml

I am loading a xml file and I want to replace the dot with a comma from the xml price output.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach( $xml->product as $product ){
    echo $product->manufacturerSKU;
    echo $product-minPriceInfo->price;
}
```

I tried

```
$product = str_replace(',', '.', $product );
```

but I does not work on the xml output.
Thanks in advance.

Nils

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Write your string before `str_replace` and after `str_replace` function.

Comment: You say it does not work on the XML OUTPUT. Do you mean you want to amend that actual content of the XML File or just change it for your own display purposes

Comment: `$product-minPriceInfo->price` is an instance of `SimpleXMLElement`, the reason why you can `echo` it, is because of `SimpleXMLElement::__toString`, calling `str_replace` on `$product` in the way you're doing reassigns `$product` and turns it into a string, so you can't write things like `$product->manufacturerSKU;` (trying to access property of a non-object). Also: `$product-minPriceInfo->price` is a syntax error, no matter what `$product` is

Comment: The output which is display is just a number like 5.231 and I need the dot replaced with comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something simple like this

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
foreach( $xml->product as $product ){
    echo $product->manufacturerSKU;
    echo str_replace('.', ',', $product->minPriceInfo->price);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you said you want to replace every comma with a dot, but you mixed up the parameters:

```
//replaces every , with a .
$string = str_replace(',', '.', $string);

//replaces every . with a ,
$string = str_replace('.', ',', $string);
```

the syntax for [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) is `string str_replace($search,$replace,$subject);`

Answer (score 0):

can you also try something like this as well, 
just an optional way of doing it

```
// english notation without thousands separator
$product = number_format((float)$product->minPriceInfo->price, 2, ',', '');
```